# Why there is no "additional_data" in Azure SQL sys.event_log table?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have Azure SQL Data Base

Server version V12
Pricing tier Basic (5 DTUs)

After a few deadlocks, there is no info in the column additional_data in table sys.event_log.

Running the following script on the "master" DB:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.event_log WHERE event_type = 'deadlock'
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dn270018.aspx),i could see:

> The following query returns all deadlock events for database Database1 (applies only to Azure SQL Database V11).

```
SELECT * FROM sys.event_log   
WHERE event_type = 'deadlock'   
    AND database_name = 'Database1';
```

> The following query returns all deadlock events for database Database1 (applies only to Azure SQL Database V12).

```
WITH CTE AS (  
       SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML)  AS [target_data_XML]   
   FROM sys.fn_xe_telemetry_blob_target_read_file('dl', null, null, null)  
)  
SELECT target_data_XML.value('(/event/@timestamp)[1]', 'DateTime2') AS Timestamp,  
target_data_XML.query('/event/data[@name=''xml_report'']/value/deadlock') AS deadlock_xml,  
target_data_XML.query('/event/data[@name=''database_name'']/value').value('(/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS db_name  
FROM CTE
```